# Windows Phone 8.1 - Textbox not accessible for editing

Tags: webview, textbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I have a webview and a TextBox in same grid on a page. TextBox is for copying text to clipboard so the user has to interact with it to copy the text. I am using the visibility.collapsed to Show the webview or to collapse it and Show the TextBox.

The Problem occurs when I use the webview and then collaps it and Show the TextBox, I can't interact with the TextBox any more. I can tap on it and it Looks like focused but I can't interact with it. I can't copy the text or mark it for copy. I must also say that a messagebox appears when switching from webview to TextBox (I did this). maybe this is impoortant for you.

How can I bring the TextBox's functionality back? And the funny Thing is that sometimes (rarely) it works. But when it is not working any more than it doesn't work until you Close the app completely and open it again.

Comment: You might want to try to set a large margin for the control you do not want to be displayed instead of collapsing. Maybe this will solve the problem.